# Push Notification result 87

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am sending push notification in php I got "87" in result variable. what does it means.

```
    <?php
    $deviceToken = "a448b8946a5de3801dc6a11862a5a0bf11f1adc16xxxxxxxxxxxx"; // masked for security reason
    // Passphrase for the private key
    $pass = 'molik';

    // Get the parameters from http get or from command line
    $message = $_GET['message'] or $message = $argv[1] or $message = 'Test Message';
    //$badge = (int)$_GET['badge'] or $badge = (int)$argv[2] or $badge  = 1;
    $sound = $_GET['sound'] or $sound = $argv[3] or $sound  = 'default';

    // Construct the notification payload
    $body = array();
    $body['aps'] = array('alert' => $message);
    if ($badge)
    $body['aps']['badge'] = $badge;
    if ($sound)
    $body['aps']['sound'] = $sound;


    /* End of Configurable Items */
    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
    // assume the private key passphase was removed.
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $pass);

    // for production change the server to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:219
    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp) {
        print "Failed to connect $err $errstr\n";
        return;
    }
    else {
        print "Connection OK\n";
    }

    $payload = json_encode($body);
    $msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    print "sending message :" . $payload . "\n";

     $result=fwrite($fp, $msg);

     echo ">>" .$result ."<<" . PHP_EOL;
     fclose($fp);
```

**OutPut**

```
 Connection OK
 sending message :{"aps":{"alert":"Test Message","sound":"default"}}
 >>87<<
```

Comment: Where exactly does the output ">>87<<" come from? You code snippet ends on the line that prints "sending message" and the message, so there is no way yet of determining where this comes from.

Comment: triphoenix below is correct: the number u receive is the bytes written by fwrite. But u can use this for error checking because if you receive a 0 response back it means that fwrite was unable to write anything, probably because Apple closed the server connection. So its not the fwrite with the 0 response that is the problem, it is a previous fwrite that was succesfully sent, but there was something about it that apple did not like, so they closed the server connection. If you use "ORDER BY id" with SELECT statement then u can figure out approx where problem occured & continue PUSH from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP `fwrite` returns the number of characters written, in this case the number of bytes written to your socket.